# CakePHP Database Structure Multiple Relationships

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

In my simple system there is a users table where user logins and passwords are stored as well as a customers table.

Users can be related to customers in 3 different ways. 
1) Sales Representative to the customer
2) Lead generated by this customer
3) Customer account entered by this rep

Originally I planned on having all on the customers table:
customers.user_id customers.lead_id customers.entered_by_id.

With CakePHP is this the wrong way? How should it be designed?
I am 1 day new to CakePHP.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about what you are building and your requirements, this is what I would do:

- `users`: contains *just* authentication info

  - `users.role`: useful for querying what role a specific user is (customer, sales rep, admin, etc.)
  - `users.username`
  - `users.password`
- `sales_representatives`: contains sales rep data

  - `sales_representatives.user_id`: Links the sales rep data to a specific user
- `customers`: contains customer data

  - `customers.user_id`: Links the user to a specific user (assuming you want them to log in, if not you can skip this)
  - `customers.sales_representative_id`: Links a customer to a sales rep. You might want to store a history of sales reps for a specific customer in a separate table, but this field is just the current sales rep.
  - `customers.lead_id`: Links to a specific lead this customer came from. Can be null in case it was inbound and not a lead, but will probably link to something useful.
- `leads`: Contains lead data

  - `leads.sales_representative_id`: Contains the current sales rep for a given lead. As with the customers table, you might want to store a list of historical sales reps for a given lead in a separate table.

You might also optionally add a `user_id` to the lead table if a lead can login, but that might not be the case in your system.

What is your `entered_by_id`? That seems more like a lead-related id, in which case you may want to track that in the leads table (separate from the `sales_representative_id`).

Most of this stuff isn't CakePHP-related, though good schema planning will go a long way to making using CakePHP easy :)